# iis 7 site not working on iis 8.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

I have a .NET Framework 4 site hosted by IIS 7 on a Windows Server 2008 machine. It works well. When I created a new site with IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 machine referring to the same physical path, the new site returns this error:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:
Create the content on the Web server.
Review the browser URL.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:9009/Migrate/LBEService/Service1.svc/GetAuthenInfo
Physical Path      \\FILESERVER\tech_share\Sites\LBS_ADOT2\Migrate\LBEService\Service1.svc\GetAuthenInfo
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

More Information:
This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again.
View more information »
```

What could be the issue causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your IIS  worker process [identity](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx) is not able to read the path .

> Please make sure your application pool identity has access to the UNC path
>   \FILESERVER\tech_share\Sites\LBS_ADOT2\Migrate\LBEService\

You can check the identity is same as in the working machine

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx